# Networkx Kernighan-Lin multipartition

Tags: python, graph, networkx, partitioning

I made a graph and I separate it into 2 parts by the Kernighan-Lin partitioning algorithm. In NetworkX package in python has the Kernighan-Lin algorithm just for two partitions but I need it for multipartition. How can I change it from two partitions to multipartition?

There is a code of sample graph that I made and also the Kernighan-Lin algorithm.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import islice
from operator import itemgetter
import networkx as nx
from networkx.utils import not_implemented_for, py_random_state
from networkx.algorithms.community.community_utils import is_partition

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node('a')
G.add_node('b')
G.add_node('c')
G.add_node('d')
G.add_node('e')
G.add_node('f')
G.add_edge('a','b')
G.add_edge('c','b')
G.add_edge('d','e')
G.add_edge('e','f')

__all__ = ['kernighan_lin_bisection']

def _compute_delta(G, A, B, weight):
    delta = defaultdict(float)
    for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True):
        w = d.get(weight, 1)
        if u in A:
            if v in A:
                delta[u] -= w
                delta[v] -= w
            elif v in B:
                delta[u] += w
                delta[v] += w
        elif u in B:
            if v in A:
                delta[u] += w
                delta[v] += w
            elif v in B:
                delta[u] -= w
                delta[v] -= w
    return delta

def _update_delta(delta, G, A, B, u, v, weight):
    for _, nbr, d in G.edges(u, data=True):
        w = d.get(weight, 1)
        if nbr in A:
            delta[nbr] += 2 * w
        if nbr in B:
            delta[nbr] -= 2 * w
    for _, nbr, d in G.edges(v, data=True):
        w = d.get(weight, 1)
        if nbr in A:
            delta[nbr] -= 2 * w
        if nbr in B:
            delta[nbr] += 2 * w
    return delta

def _kernighan_lin_pass(G, A, B, weight):
    multigraph = G.is_multigraph()
    delta = _compute_delta(G, A, B, weight)
    swapped = set()
    gains = []
    while len(swapped) < len(G):
        gain = []
        for u in A - swapped:
            for v in B - swapped:
                try:
                    if multigraph:
                        w = sum(d.get(weight, 1) for d in G[u][v].values())
                    else:
                        w = G[u][v].get(weight, 1)
                except KeyError:
                    w = 0
                gain.append((delta[u] + delta[v] - 2 * w, u, v))
        if len(gain) == 0:
            break
        maxg, u, v = max(gain, key=itemgetter(0))
        swapped |= {u, v}
        gains.append((maxg, u, v))
        delta = _update_delta(delta, G, A - swapped, B - swapped, u, v, weight)
    return gains

@py_random_state(4)
@not_implemented_for('directed')
def kernighan_lin_bisection(G, partition=None, max_iter=10, weight='weight',seed=None):
    if partition is None:
        nodes = list(G)
        seed.shuffle(nodes)
        h = len(nodes) // 2
        partition = (nodes[:h], nodes[h:])
    try:
        A, B = set(partition[0]), set(partition[1])
    except:
        raise ValueError('partition must be two sets')
    if not is_partition(G, (A, B)):
        raise nx.NetworkXError('partition invalid')
    for i in range(max_iter):
        gains = _kernighan_lin_pass(G, A, B, weight)
        csum = list(nx.utils.accumulate(g for g, u, v in gains))
        max_cgain = max(csum)
        if max_cgain <= 0:
            break
        index = csum.index(max_cgain)
        nodesets = islice(zip(*gains[:index + 1]), 1, 3)
        anodes, bnodes = (set(s) for s in nodesets)
        A |= bnodes
        A -= anodes
        B |= anodes
        B -= bnodes
        return A, B

def main() -> None:
kl = kernighan_lin_bisection(G, partition=None, max_iter=10, weight='weight',seed=None)
print(f'= {kl}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Metis algorithm to have a multi partition